# How do I solve an error in x : non-conformable arguments (R)?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, ordinal

I am trying to implement ordinal logistic regression on my dataset in r.  I use the function 'polr' for this, but cannot seem to find a lot of information regarding its implementation.
The following errors are the ones I'm stuck on:

```
> dat.polr <- polr(as.factor(relevance)~allterms+idf.title, data=dat.one)
Warning message:
In polr(as.factor(relevance) ~ allterms + idf.title + idf.desc +  :
  design appears to be rank-deficient, so dropping some coefs
> dat.pred <- predict(dat.polr,dat.test,type="class")
Error in X %*% object$coefficients : non-conformable arguments
```

I want to train my model to guess the relevance of a new dataset. dat.one is the dataset I'm using to train the data, dat.test is the dataset I'm using to test the data. I believe that the predict variable's error is caused by the warning in polr. However, I have no clue how to resolve this. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What does `table(dat.one$relevance)` show?

Comment: @GregorThomas I have resolved the first error thanks to this comment! Something went wrong when creating day.one and table(dat.one$relevance) now shows only 1, 2 or 3. I am still getting the second error though: I edited my question

Comment: A rank-deficient matrix is  where some columns are not linearly independent. You maybe have a couple columns (or levels of columns) that always co-occur, and the model can't tell the difference between them, so it just drops one and uses the other. Solutions would be (a) letting it go - it's a warning, not an error. You can still see results. (b) Figuring out which variable(s) are causing the issue and making a judgement call on which to include. (c) Getting more data and hoping to see some variation... Probably other options too. You may need to omit those variables from the prediction data.

Comment: Can't really tell you what to do without context about your data and goals - and picking an option for your situation is more of a methodological question than a programming one - it would fit better at stats.stackexchange.com than here. If you pick an option and need help implementing it, that would be good here. But you'll need to share some sample data for us to work with.